# Stream Internal Iphone Camera over Localhost

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, stream

Is there any way through which i can stream my Internal IPhone camera over Localhost, where the iphone device and the computer are in same network and when you start the stream it would be visible into the browser.

As if now i have created a TCP Webserver into the app where on localhost an html page gets loaded ,now i am stuck how to access the camera and stream over localhost inside HTML page. As i have found some of the libraries but they need Internet Connection to stream and compressing the videos.